# SQL Find maximum then find occurances thereof

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, max

I cannot get this to work. **I need to first find the maximum sum of vacation and sick leave hours, then find which employees who have this value for their sum of vacation and sick leave hours.** I can get the 168 max, but regardless of how I arrange things I cannot seem to then get just the employees who match this criteria - I just get a full list of all employees. Code below is last attempt, based on class direction. Thanks!

```
SELECT e.employeeID, SUM(e.vacationhours + e.sickleavehours) AS maxHours
    FROM   humanresources.employee e 
    WHERE  EXISTS (
                   SELECT SUM(e.vacationhours + e.sickleavehours) AS totalhours 
                   FROM   humanresources.employee e) 
    GROUP  BY e.employeeID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go for this, without using specific SQL server syntax. I guess this should work in most DBMS:

```
SELECT e.employeeID,
    SUM(e.vacationhours + e.sickleavehours) AS totalHours
FROM humanresources.employee e 
GROUP BY e.employeeID
HAVING SUM(e.vacationhours + e.sickleavehours) >= all
  (SELECT SUM(e.vacationhours + e.sickleavehours) FROM humanresources
   GROUP BY employeeID)
```

Comment: This was similar to what I was thinking...  but I think the sub-query in the `having` has to be a `max` of the `sum` grouped by `employeeID`... which then makes me think of using a cte to remove the duplication... which then eliminates the need for the `having` clause... which then makes me wonder exactly what the teacher is trying to elicit with the question...

Comment: Thanks! This is what I'm going with - actually just figured it out moments ago. I was leaving the second part of the having as a simple max function, which I assume was then equating the sum and the max on the same row, and thus getting my entire employee table each time.

Comment: @VOlvox , Michael is absolutely right. I've just updated the answer. Now it should be bullet proof :) Thanks Michael :)

Answer (score 7):

[`TOP WITH TIES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) simplifies this problem...

If you just want a list of employees who have the maximum number of totalHours... you can simply order by the sum, and select the top 1, including any ties so that it returns all employees with the max values:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
    e.employeeID,
    SUM(e.vacationhours + e.sickleavehours) AS totalHours
FROM humanresources.employee e 
GROUP BY e.employeeID
ORDER BY totalHours DESC;
```

Comment: Creative and elegant; but likely not what the teacher will be expecting.  To summarize what is being done here for Volvox:  Michael is summing all the employees totalHours ordering the results so that the those with the most hours appear first, then only returning the first result including ties.

Comment: +1 Interesting! Thanks for this, have to look at it in the future... no way I can submit something like this. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `Having` clause

Answer (score 0):

You have one table called `employee` and in that table you have a field called `employeeID`. Unless this is a case of a very bad naming the `employeeID` is the primary key of the `employee` table.

There is no need to do a `group by`. You can filter your rows in the where clause.

```
select e.employeeID, e.vacationhours + e.sickleavehours as Hours
from employee as e
where e.vacationhours + e.sickleavehours = (select max(vacationhours + sickleavehours)
                                            from employee)
```